# Alterar ordem das plotagens de um gráfico de área no R

Tags: r, ggplot2, gráfico

Estou utilizando o seguinte código para tentar plotar um gráfico

```
ggplot(final2, aes(x = final2$a, y =final2$somaacumulada,fill=final2$Country)) +
  theme_bw()+
  geom_area(position = position_dodge(width = 0.8))
```

Esta é uma parte do data frame dos dados

```
"Rated Power","Country","Commissioned","d","m","a","somaacumulada"
1.14,"Resto do mundo","01.01.1985",1,1,1985,17451.5
1.28,"Japan","01.01.1995",1,1,1995,16969.78
1.7,"Resto do mundo","01.01.1966",1,1,1966,2542.3
2,"China","01.11.1992",1,11,1992,485
3.5,"Germany","01.01.1973",1,1,1973,1346.7
3.6,"Spain","01.01.1955",1,1,1955,10.8
4.6,"Resto do mundo","01.01.1957",1,1,1957,238.6
7,"Austria","01.01.1969",1,1,1969,352
7.2,"Spain","01.01.1929",1,1,1929,7.2
8.5,"United States","01.01.1954",1,1,1954,37.5
11,"France","01.01.1951",1,1,1951,11
11.3,"Spain","27.06.2014",27,6,2014,6758.7
12,"India","01.01.1976",1,1,1976,162
13.5,"Japan","01.01.1961",1,1,1961,13.5
14,"Spain","01.01.1966",1,1,1966,339.8
15.9,"Resto do mundo","01.01.1969",1,1,1969,2758.2
17,"Resto do mundo","01.01.1986",1,1,1986,18791.5
22,"China","01.11.1973",1,11,1973,63
24,"Resto do mundo","01.01.1953",1,1,1953,234
25.2,"United States","01.01.1973",1,1,1973,6518.7
28,"United States","01.01.1972",1,1,1972,5277.5
29,"United States","01.01.1929",1,1,1929,29
30,"Resto do mundo","01.01.1937",1,1,1937,165
30.8,"Resto do mundo","01.01.1989",1,1,1989,20912.3
35,"Germany","01.01.1959",1,1,1959,404
36.5,"Italy","01.01.1965",1,1,1965,489.7
37,"Resto do mundo","31.12.2016",31,12,2016,33017.7
40,"Resto do mundo","01.01.1974",1,1,1974,5482.2
40,"United States","14.09.2012",14,9,2012,22560.7
41,"China","01.05.1968",1,5,1968,41
42,"Italy","01.01.1968",1,1,1968,646.7
45,"Resto do mundo","01.01.1944",1,1,1944,210
45,"United States","01.01.1994",1,1,1994,21425.7
48,"France","01.01.1957",1,1,1957,59
49,"Germany","01.01.1983",1,1,1983,3999.7
49.2,"Germany","01.01.1960",1,1,1960,453.2
50,"Austria","01.01.2011",1,1,2011,3200
50,"United States","01.08.1971",1,8,1971,5249.5
53,"Resto do mundo","01.01.1990",1,1,1990,20965.3
54,"Spain","01.01.1982",1,1,1982,2561.3
58,"United States","01.01.1984",1,1,1984,15300.9
```

Porem não estou conseguindo fazer ficar direitinho a ordem das áreas, as áreas maiores que ficam na frente do gráfico e escondem as menores que ficam atrás, alguém saberia de uma maneira para resolver isso?[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Outra dúvida que eu tenho seria para limitar no eixo X os valores para ter um intervalo que represente melhor o gráfico.

EDIT --

Fiz as seguintes edições:

```
final2$Country <- factor(final2$Country, levels = c('Resto do mundo','United States','Japan','China','Italy','Germany','Spain','France','India','Austria'))

ggplot(final2, aes(x = Commissioned, y =somaacumulada)) +
  theme_bw()+
  geom_area(position = position_dodge(width = 0.8),alpha=1, aes(fill=Country)) +
  scale_x_date(breaks= "10 years", labels = date_format("%Y"))+
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(0,37000,1000)) +
  xlab('Ano') +ylab('Potência Instalada [MW]')
```

E obtive o seguinte resultado
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

porem o resultado não está condizente, ainda tem alguns valores escondidos e, como estou utilizando soma acumulada, os valores de qualquer país não deveriam diminuir de um ano para outro, ou aumenta ou continuam constantes.

Comment: Em `aes(...)` não precisa de `final2$`. Remova e tente outra vez.

Comment: Tente sempre deixar um exemplo reproduzível, para poder receber uma resposta. O problema de sobreposição de áreas, tente ordenar os dados com ```arrange``` ou equivalente. Quanto ao limite para o eixo x, tente ```coord_cartesian(xlim = c(limite inferior, limite superior))```.

Comment: @AlexandreSanches Ou filtrar os zeros, pelo aspeto do gráfico há zeros até pós 1950.

Comment: vc pode mudar a opacidade atravez do alpha

Comment: @AlexandreSanches Não entendi o que você quis dizer com o exemplo reproduzível. Agradeço pelo código do limite, funcionou perfeitamente! Não tem zeros após 1950, o que acontece é que de alguns dados se mantem constante até 2019.

Comment: @Bruno Obrigado! Estava usando a opacidade para conseguir enxergar os dados escondidos, mas no produto final preciso deles com opacidade 0

Comment: Sempre procure postar um exemplo reproduzível para podermos replicar seus dados e chegar em soluções. Por exemplo, você postou seu código, mas eu não tenho como testá-lo em minha versão do R pois não possuo os dados e você não colocou nenhum dado de exemplo.

Comment: @RuiBarradas fiz o que você falou e obtive o mesmo resultado.

Comment: @AlexandreSanches Inseri uma parte dos dados

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aqui estão duas soluções para o problema. Ambas ordenam os países da maior `somaacumulada` para a menor mas fazem-no de formas diferentes e as ordens finais são diferentes. Em ambas as soluções `Country` passa a ser uma coluna de classe `"factor"`, com níveis diferentes, consoante a ordem de `somaacumulada`.

**1.** Carregar o pacote `ggplot2` e transformar as datas em verdadeiras datas.

```
library(ggplot2)

final2$Commissioned <- as.Date(final2$Commissioned, "%d.%m.%Y")
```

**2. Primeira solução.**

Esta solução ordena os países por data de `Commissioned` e `somaacumulada`.

1. Criar um índice `i`;
2. Criar um vetor de níveis para o fator `Country` por ordem de `i`.
3. Criar o fator com esses níveis.

O resultado é termos as somas acumuladas maiores à *última data* em último plano, depois as segundas maiores, etc. As áreas menores ficam em primeiro plano mas *só as que chegam ao último dia*.

```
i <- with(final2, order(Commissioned, somaacumulada, decreasing = TRUE))
lvls <- unique(final2$Country[i])
final2$Country <- factor(final2$Country, levels = lvls)

ggplot(final2, aes(x = a, y = somaacumulada, fill = Country)) +
  geom_area(position = position_dodge(width = 0.8)) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**3. Segunda solução.**

Agora ordenam-se os países por `somaacumulada` máxima, sem ter em conta as datas. As intruções gráficas são exatamente as mesmas.

```
m <- with(final2, tapply(somaacumulada, Country, max))
m <- sort(m, decreasing = TRUE)
lvls <- unique(names(m))
final2$Country <- factor(final2$Country, levels = lvls)

ggplot(final2, aes(x = a, y = somaacumulada, fill = Country)) +
  geom_area(position = position_dodge(width = 0.8)) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

## Edição

Para responder à pergunta em comentário, como acrescentar uma linha por país para o ano de 2019 com os mesmos dados da última linha desse país, caso ainda não haja dados para 2019, o código seguinte é uma solução em R base.

```
ano <- 2019
d.ano <- as.Date(paste(ano, 1, 1, sep = '-'))
sp <- split(final2, final2$Country)

sp <- lapply(sp, function(X){
  n <- nrow(X)
  if(X[n, 'a'] < ano){
    new <- X[n,, drop = FALSE]
    new$Commissioned <- d.ano
    new$d <- 1
    new$m <- 1
    new$a <- ano
  }
  rbind(X, new)
})
novo <- do.call(rbind, sp)
row.names(novo) <- gsub('[^[:digit:]]+', '', row.names(novo))
novo <- novo[order(as.integer(row.names(novo))), ]
novo
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pelas respostas, me ajudou muito!! Agora uma dúvida, teria um jeito mais fácil de colocar os valores que não tem dados para o ano de 2019 como constantes até 2019? Pelo meu pouco conhecimento eu adicionaria mais uma linha no dataframe com a data de 2019 para a Itália, por exemplo, e repetiria o ultimo valor da coluna somaacumulada para deixar constante, faria isso para todos os outros casos. Tem uma forma mais fácil de fazer isso?

Comment: @MatheusDias Isso é uma pergunta diferente mas vou editar com uma maneira de fazer isso.